# File Androidapi.JNI.JavaUtil not found

Tags: android, delphi

I'm using `Delphi 10.3 CE`. I'm trying to compile a project (Grijjy DelphiGoogleSignIn) that uses `Androidapi.JNI.JavaUtil`. Compiler tells me file not found. There is no file by that name in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0` Delphi installation and I cannot find any mention of it being removed or renamed by Embarcadero. Does anyone know whether this file exists?

Comment: It's on my machine, in the source\rtl\android folder.

Comment: @KenWhite It's not on my machine. Are you using Delphi 10.3? Could you possibly send the source file to me? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is not included in the CE edition?

Comment: No, I can't send the source files to you. That would violate both my license for RAD Studio and yours. I'm guessing mobile development isn't available in the CE version. Contact EMBT to see about upgrading to a higher SKU that includes that functionality.

Comment: I have recently installed Enterprise version of 10.3.3 and that file does not exist for me also. I'm upgrading from 10.2.3. So far, I have just commented it out from a few units and the projects compile OK. But this is a worry if @Ken has the file and we do not.

Comment: And looking at the code for it from 10.2.3, it looks like the code from JavaUtil has been absorbed into Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes